# Jest test fail: "● default root route"

Tags: node.js, jestjs, fastify

I'm trying to write Jest tests for a Fastify project. But I'm stuck with the example code failing with an ambiguous error: "● default root route".

```
// root.test.ts
import { build } from '../helper'

const app = build()

test('default root route', async () => {
  const res = await app.inject({
    url: '/'
  })
  expect(res.json()).toEqual({ root: true })
})
```

```
// helper.ts
import Fastify from "fastify"
import fp from "fastify-plugin"
import App from "../src/app"

export function build() {
  const app = Fastify()

  beforeAll(async () => {
    void app.register(fp(App))
    await app.ready()
  })

  afterAll(() => app.close())

  return app
}
```

```
// console error:
 FAIL  test/routes/root.test.ts (8.547 s)
  ● default root route





A worker process has failed to exit gracefully and has been force exited. This is likely caused by tests leaking due to improper teardown. Try running with --detectOpenHandles to find leaks. Active timers can also cause this, ensure that .unref() was called on them.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see the beforeall/afterall import and I think these functions call must be in root.test file

Comment: Did you run it with `--detectOpenHandles`? The message implies something caused your app to hang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running `--detectOpenHandles`, Jest reported that open `ioredis` connections were timing out.

I hooked up ioredis instances to Fastify lifecycle with `fastify-redis` and the test passed.